# Use SequenceMatcher in array column in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame with one array column ‘test’ in pyspark dataframe have 3 or more rows.

test ———————————————————————— [‘hello’,’hell’,’Help’,’helper’] [‘matter’,’matt’,mater’] [‘sequence’,’seque’]

How can I use difflib.sequencematcher to iterate over each element of rows and if ratio of two element less than 90% then append both the elements in a new column say ‘test_ratio and if it is greater then just keep one element from two?

Example : From first row Compare first two element ‘hello’ and ‘hell’ if ratio greater then 90% then append hello into test_ratio then compare hello with help if ratio less then 90% then just append hepl then compare hello with helper and since both are different then append helper and so on. Basically i want keep distinct element in array having similitude index less then 90%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) that filters the arrays. The logic inside the udf compares the first element of each array with all other elements of the same array and keeps only those strings where [ratio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) returns a value less or equal 0.9.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data = [[['hello','hell','Help','helper']],[['matter','matt','mater']],[['sequence','seque']]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["test"])

@F.udf(returnType=T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def almost_distinct_values(inp):
    from difflib import SequenceMatcher
    return [inp[0]]+ [v for v in inp[1:] if SequenceMatcher(None, inp[0],v).ratio() <= 0.9]
    
df.withColumn("test_ratio", almost_distinct_values("test")).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
df.withColumn("test_ratio", almost_distinct_values("test")).show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|test                       |test_ratio                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|[hello, hell, Help, helper]|[hello, hell, Help, helper]|
|[matter, matt, mater]      |[matter, matt]             |
|[sequence, seque]          |[sequence, seque]          |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```